# Filtering nested object by value

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a structure similar to that **(1)**:

```
data = {
RESULT: {
    GROUPS: {
        GROUP: [
            {
                KEY1: "value 1",
                KEY2: "value 2",
                MYKEY: "MYVALUE"

            },
            {
                KEY1: "value 1",
                KEY2: "value 2",
                MYKEY: "another value"

            }
        ]
    }
},
ANOTHERKEY: "another value",
MOREKEYS: "more values"
}
```

Where `GROUP` could contain multiple values (like in this case) or just one **(2)**:

```
...
GROUPS: {
    GROUP: {
            KEY1: "value 1",
            KEY2: "value 2",
            MYKEY: "MYVALUE"

        }
}
```

---

I need to remove all elements of `GROUP` where `MYKEY` has NOT the value `MYVALUE`.

In both cases (1 and 2) the final output should look like:

```
{
   "RESULT":{
      "GROUPS":{
         "GROUP":{
            "KEY1":"value 1",
            "KEY2":"value 2",
            "MYKEY":"MYVALUE"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

My approach was to use a filter:

```
newObj = Object.values(data.RESULT.GROUPS.GROUP).filter(e => e.MYKEY === 'MYVALUE');
```

In the case with multiple `GROUP` elements **(1)**, it filters correctly, but returns me only the element itself:

```
[{
  KEY1: "value 1",
  KEY2: "value 2",
  MYKEY: "MYVALUE"
}]
```

instead of the entire object beginning from `RESULT`.

If there is only one `GROUP` element **(2)**, it returns me an empty object:

```
[]
```

Comment: _"If there is only one GROUP element (2)"_ - Then the value of that property should also be an array and not an object.

Comment: Just because you can write something in one line does not make it a valuable solution. Check the type of `data.RESULT.GROUPS.GROUP` and act accordingly (`Object.values()` is the wrong tool)

Comment: Let us consider case `(1)` where the `GROUP` is an array. In that case, if there were more objects where `MYKEY: "MYVALUE"`, then is it okay to just retain the first object & discard the remaining?

Comment: The first problem is that `filter` returns an array, and to fix that you need to constuct the "result object" with `GROUPS` and `GROUP` and populate that from the filtered array. The second problem is that when there's only one group, you need to treat it differently as it is not an array but an object.

Comment: @jsN00b: I need all remaining objects (where `MYKEY: "MYVALUE"`). Only where `MYKEY != "MYVALUE"` should be removed.

Comment: In that case, `GROUP` will need to be either an array or an object - or is it okay to have an array (even if only one is matched)? Please update the question to show the desired target and will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification from OP, the below may be a solution that achieves the desired objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const findAndfilterGroup = (src, tgt) => {
  if (typeof src === 'object') {
    Object.entries(src).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (k === 'GROUP') {
        const res = [].concat(v).filter(
          ({MYKEY}) => MYKEY === 'MYVALUE'
        );
        tgt = {
          ...tgt,
          GROUP: (
            res.length > 1
              ? res
              : res.length === 1
                ? {...res[0]}
                : {filter: 'MYVALUE not found'}
          )
        }
      }
      else {
        if (typeof v === 'object') tgt = {...tgt, [k]: findAndfilterGroup({...v}, {})}
        else tgt = {...tgt, [k]: v}
      }
    });
    return tgt;
  }
  else {}
};

const customFilter = obj => {
  return findAndfilterGroup({...obj}, {});
};

const data1 = {
  RESULT: {
    GROUPS: {
      GROUP: [{
          KEY1: "value 1",
          KEY2: "value 2",
          MYKEY: "MYVALUE"
        },
        {
          KEY1: "value 1",
          KEY2: "value 2",
          MYKEY: "another value"
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  ANOTHERKEY: "another value",
  MOREKEYS: "more values"
};

console.log('source data has GROUP as an array: ', customFilter(data1));

const data4 = {
  RESULT: {
    GROUPS: {
      GROUP: [{
          KEY1: "value 1",
          KEY2: "value 2",
          MYKEY: "MYVALUE"
        },
        {
          KEY1: "value 1",
          KEY2: "value 2",
          MYKEY: "another value"
        },
        {
          KEY1: "value 77",
          KEY2: "value 78",
          MYKEY: "MYVALUE"
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  ANOTHERKEY: "another value",
  MOREKEYS: "more values"
};

console.log('source data GROUP multiple matches: ', customFilter(data4));

const data2 = {
  RESULT: {
    GROUPS2: {
      GROUP: {
        KEY1: "value 1",
        KEY2: "value 2",
        MYKEY: "MYVALUE"
      }
    }
  },
  ANOTHERKEY: "another value",
  MOREKEYS: "more values"
};

console.log('GROUP as an object: ', customFilter(data2));

const data3 = {
  RESULT: {
    GROUPS: {
      GROUP: [{
          KEY1: "value 1",
          KEY2: "value 2",
          MYKEY: "not my value"
        },
        {
          KEY1: "value 1",
          KEY2: "value 2",
          MYKEY: "another value"
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  ANOTHERKEY: "another value",
  MOREKEYS: "more values"
};

console.log('GROUP as an array without MYVALUE: ', customFilter(data3));
```

**Explanation**

- Simple recursion is used to trace through the object structure
- `tgt` is a placeholder for the target object structure
- When a key named `GROUP` is found, then the corresponding value is `filter`ed
- In other cases, the key-value pair is copied without manipulation
- In case of some data (such as `data3` in the snippet above) where the `GROUP` array has no matching `MYVALUE`, a message is added within the object structure.
- Based on the requirement, one may alter this to `console.log` or `throw` error

**EDIT**

Updated as per clarification in comments.

> I need all remaining objects (where MYKEY: "MYVALUE")